# How to handle whitespaces from \hangindent?

Tags: indentation, white-space

There is the problem with `\hangindent`.
Here is the code which I've used:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[matrix,arrow,curve]{xy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% SIZES
\textwidth=15.0 cm
\textheight=21.0 cm
\hoffset=-1cm
\voffset=-2cm

\setlength{\unitlength}{1.09mm}


\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
    \lipsum[1]
    \hangindent=-5cm \hangafter=-6

    \lipsum[2]
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

And the document which this code products:
[image]
Here you see two indented blocks in the `proof` environment. Meanwhile I need only **one** indented block. If you try to continue this process --- indenting continues on and on for each new white row. How can I handle it? I need it **in** `proof` environment.

**UPD** Here is some code, but it still indents both of the paragraphs:

```tex
\begin{proof}           
        
    \hangindent=-5cm \hangafter=-5
    \lipsum[1] \\
    
    \lipsum[2]
\end{proof}
```

**UPD2** All I needed to do is brackets:

```tex
\begin{proof}           
        
    {\hangindent=-5cm \hangafter=-5
    \lipsum[1] \par} 
    
    \lipsum[2]
\end{proof}
```

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- show us a short tex code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: @Mensch, I've written commands which are rising the error, what else can I provide here?

Comment: Start with `\documentclass` and end the code with `\end{document}`, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch haha, that's so funny! (no actually) That's a long paper, so I can describe only my usages and redefines

Comment: Use the `lipsum` package to get reams of text. All you have said is that you use the `\hang...` macros, not how you use them in relation to the text.

Comment: @PeterWilson, the problem is that with ```lipsum``` this problem not arises

Comment: @taciturno The code doesn't produce the image you show.

Comment: @egreg, my bad, edited the code

Comment: Waiting for the question to be reopened, the problem is that `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` must go at the beginning of a paragraph (after a blank line and with no intervening blank line), not at the end. The double indentation is a byproduct of `\lipsum`.

Comment: @egreg, can you please provide code --- I can't improve my example with ```lipsum```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions

```
\hangindent=-5cm \hangafter=-6
```

mean that in the *current* paragraph we want to shorten the first six lines to a length of 5cm less than the standard width.

Note that “current paragraph” is the key. The instructions can be pretty anywhere in the paragraph, but it's best to place them at the very beginning so you can spot them.

In your case, some quirks of `lipsum` enter into the scene, but you will get away with

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc} % ?
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{amscd} % ?
\usepackage[matrix,arrow,curve]{xy}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%% don't use such settings! Use geometry
%% SIZES
%\textwidth=15.0 cm
%\textheight=21.0 cm
%\hoffset=-1cm
%\voffset=-2cm
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  textwidth=15cm,
  textheight=21cm,
}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1.09mm} % ?


\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, фацете еурипидис еу вел. Еу цоммодо воцибус 
фацилис еос. Ан бруте патриояуе витуператорибус еум, феугиат пхаедрум пер 
еу, ерос опортере ет вим. Омиттам репудиаре ан цум, ид меа муциус фацилиси 
менандри. Ипсум малуиссет при ут. Меи еи агам алтерум партиендо, ид еос 
волумус сцаевола волуптариа, ин мунди нонумы поссит яуо.

\hangindent=-5cm \hangafter=-6
Аудире салутатус усу но, антиопам персеяуерис иус не, вим сонет солеат 
сентентиае ут. Еу яуо ехерци фиерент волуптариа, хас пробо сцрипсерит еа, 
ин цетерос сусципит детрахит еум. Пауло тритани волуптатум при ет, ех юсто 
фугит про. Омнесяуе елеифенд не усу, ет путент персецути меа. Еа сумо 
малуиссет мел, но вел нибх ехпетенда. Еу ест дицо молестиае. Еу дицам 
урбанитас иус, ад тимеам луцилиус праесент при. Дебитис медиоцрем 
продессет ут усу, иус ид амет утинам. Ферри персеяуерис ат дуо, еу 
усу тота урбанитас. Ех доцтус вивендо легендос пер.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Leave a blank line before the instructions and no blank line after it.

I've made some other changes to your code. Use UTF-8, not cp1251, if you can. I don't think you need both `xy` and `amscd` (the latter producing diagrams with much lower quality than the former). Don't hand craft page parameters, use `geometry`: beware that setting `\hoffset` may have adverse effects with graphics packages. I commented out some packages that aren't involved in the issue at hand.

I used a [“Russian lipsum generator”](https://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/_russian) to get the text.

[image]

Comment: Does this mean that I _can't_ make an indentation with first 5 lines?

Comment: @taciturno Use `\hangafter=-5`

Comment: I mean that if I'm trying to indent _first_ paragraph, latex instead indents both of the paragraphs (please look at the "updated" in the question for code)

Comment: I founded out the problem: I used braces for using only _particular_ paragraph

Comment: anyways, it's not working again... Some strange things happening

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that LaTeX re-defines `\par` inside the `proof` environment. Primitive `\par` creates paragraph and re-initializes the `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` primitive registers. But LaTeX re-defines `\par` (i.e. blank line) as `{\par}` inside `proof` environment. So the re-initialization is done inside a group and when the group is finished then the previous values (from previous paragraph) is restored. But you don't want to use the same values for second paragraph. You can use `\endgraf` (which is equivalent to primitive `\par`) instead the blank line:

```
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1]
\hangindent=-5cm \hangafter=-6
\endgraf
\lipsum[2]
\end{proof}
```